# Android MediaCodec Format/Resolution Change mid-stream

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm processing a live stream via `MediaCodec` and have a scenario where the `MediaFormat` changes mid-stream (ie: resolution of the video being decoded changes). Given I'm attaching the decoder to a `Surface` to render it as soon as I detect the change in resolution on the incoming stream I recreate the decoder before feeding it the new resolution buffer (providing it with the proper new `MediaFormat`).

I've been getting some weird errors which don't give me too much info as to what could be wrong, ie when calling `MediaCodec.configure` with the new format and same `Surface`:

```
android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffffea
  at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
  at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:577)
```

Which when fetching the `CodecException.getDiagnosticInfo` it shows nothing that I can really use to understand the reason for the failure: `android.media.MediaCodec.error_neg_22`

I've also noted the following on the logs and found some related information and am wondering if there's something I need to do regarding the `Surface` itself (like detaching it from the old instance of the decoder being giving it to the new one):

```
07-09 15:00:17.217 E/BufferQueueProducer(  139): [SurfaceView] connect(P): already connected (cur=3 req=3)
07-09 15:00:17.217 E/MediaCodec( 5388): native_window_api_connect returned an error: Invalid argument (-22)
07-09 15:00:17.218 E/MediaCodec( 5388): configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...
```

Comment: Some decoders support "adaptive playback", which allows for resolution changes mid-stream. This is a relatively new feature (4.4?). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html has some notes.

Comment: yeah unfortunately the decoder I'm using (for `video/avc`) doesn't support it (at least not on the devices I'm testing). But it's good to know such API exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like calling `stop()` and `release()` as well as reinitializing any references I had to the `getInputBuffers()` and `getOutputBuffers()` did the trick. At least I don't get the messages/exceptions anymore. Now I just need to figure out the `Surface` reference part as it seems the resized stream (when resolution changes) is still being fit in the original surface dimensions instead of adjusting the Surface for the new resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If your encoder supports adaptive playback, then apparently you can alter some codec paramaters on the fly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34427724/1048170